# Titanium.Platform.canOpenURL doesn't work on IOS 10

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am using `Ti.Platform.canOpenURL()` to open another app which worked fine before iOS 10.

But it doesn't work on iOS 10 and later.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You use `Ti.Platform.canOpenURL('<my-url>')` to check for the URL. To open the URL, you need to use `Ti.Platform.openURL('<my-url>')` instead.

Comment: thanks, but I need to use Ti.Platform.canOpenURL to check whether the next app was installed first.

Comment: Make sure you have the url schemes configured correctly inside your plist: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

[With some of the new security features of iOS9, SDK 5.1.2's canOpenUrl might fail without adding in the proper properties in the info.plist file.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-iOS9SecurityandcanOpenUrl)

Therefore, you need to add the following `key` into the `tiapp.xml` file:

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
                    <string>[Your Project Name]</string>
                    <string>[Your Second Project Name (if any)]</string>
            </array>
        </dict> 
    </plist>
</ios>
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.